# Where do you place documents belonging to a Rails app project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bdd

For every project it's like having two parts: the Rails application and then all documents and pictures related to it.

I wonder how you organize them both.

Do you put everything under the same project root folder and apply Git on that folder or don't you protect your documents with Git at all?

Then, what if the docs are too sensitive or only for owners of that project. Then I probably should't have it under the same folder right?

How have you structured both your Rails code and belonging business documents?

Share your solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're deploying with capistrano, as a lot of Rails apps are, the standard solution seems to be to keep these sorts of assets within the shared folder, and then get cap to symlink them into the application at the point of deploy.